# Multiple input format as a single one in hadoop

Tags: java, xml, hadoop

Im facing the following situation . Kindly help me . Im using hadoop Mapreduce to process XML file .

By refering this site im able to slipt my records https://gist.github.com/sritchie/808035
But when the size of XML file is larger than the Block size im not getting the proper value 
So i need to read the entire file 
For that  i got this link

https://github.com/pyongjoo/MapReduce-Example/blob/master/mysrc/XmlInputFormat.java

But now the problem is how to implement two inputformat as a single inputformat

Kindly help me soon 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
public class XmlParser11
{

        public static class XmlInputFormat1 extends TextInputFormat {

        public static final String START_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.start";
        public static final String END_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.end";

        @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
        return false;
        }


        public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
            return new XmlRecordReader();
        }

        /**
         * XMLRecordReader class to read through a given xml document to output
         * xml blocks as records as specified by the start tag and end tag
         *
         */


        public static class XmlRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
            private byte[] startTag;
            private byte[] endTag;
            private long start;
            private long end;
            private FSDataInputStream fsin;
            private DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();

            private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
            private Text value = new Text();
            @Override
            public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
                startTag = conf.get(START_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
                endTag = conf.get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
                FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
```

But not working

Answer (score 1):

Use the **isSplitable** property to specify no to split the file (even if block size is reached). This generally used when you want to ensure that a large file should be processed by a single mapper.

```
public class XmlInputFormat extends FileInputFormat {
@Override
 protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
 return false;
}

@Override
 public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,TaskAttemptContext context)
 throws IOException {
  // return your version of XML record reader
 }
}
```

Alternatively you can also increase the block size for every split using:

```
// Set the maximum split size
setMaxSplitSize(MAX_INPUT_SPLIT_SIZE);
```

Comment: but we need to write RecordReader right . I have an RecordReader for xml reader then how can i merge the wholefile reader into it